# Force End Editing on a UISearchController without animation

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uisearchcontroller

I would like to remove the searchBar form the UI when I pop my current ViewController.
Now I do this:

```
 override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
  resultSearchController.active = false //Need improvement here. remove animation
  super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
}
```

What's happening here is that the UISearchController is dismissed but with animation... And It looks very bad in the current state.
I would like it to go back to its initial state without animation before the viewController disappear with its own animation.

Comment: Is your object of class type UISearchDisplayController ? Try this: self.resultSearchController.setActive(false, animated: false). However, I am not able to test it right now and check if it compiles.

Comment: Yes, I saw that but UISearchDisplayController is deprecated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Allllright

here is the solution:

```
resultSearchController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false) { () -> Void in
  //completion block
}
```

false being the "flag" value for saying: I don't want any animation.

Comment: This won't hide the cancel Button near search bar, also next time search bar will become active with animation only after clicking the cancel button once. Seems like a bug.

Comment: Well, it does in my app though. Are you certain about this?

Comment: Yes I'm. In my scenario i overcomes this issue by popviewcontroller in the completion handler.